# Prerequisites for complex analysis by lars v ahlfors

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I want to study complex analysis(by self,as of the pandemic). I have choosen the text: complex analysis by Lars v ahlfors.

I had completed courses in Real Analysis , linear algebra  ,Abstract Algebra, ordinary differential equations ,multivariable calculus.

So is this enough to start a course in complex analysis.

And , is lars v ahlfors text good for begginers?

Comment: I have studied a good part of the book by myself and it is very nice as the author makes a few reminders throughout the book, or even full subchapters, introducing mathematical tools such as topology, which you may or may not have seen based on the course you took. So I would definitely try to give it a go if I were you

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy so i will give it a try right away. And also , do i need to take a proper course in metric  space and partial differential equations for better understanding??

Comment: I didn't see a lot of differential equations in the parts that I studied but you do need a bit of familiarity with metric spaces (only the basis though, so no worries)

Comment: Ahlfors is a decent starting text. It is perhaps a bit advanced for many students to self study, so I might suggest reading snippets of more elementary texts and choosing one you enjoy as a companion text alongside Ahlfors. Basic mathematical background along with Real Analysis should suffice.

Comment: Your background is sufficient to read Ahlfors. The first few chapters do a great job of going over the prerequisites anyway. Some people find Ahlfors difficult, but for others it's great as an introductory text in complex analysis. If you start and you find it's too difficult for you, then ask a question again to get other recommendations. The book by Remmert isn't *very* easy, but it's good and probably a bit easier than Ahlfors.